# Difference between text-transform: uppercase; and all caps

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between

```
<span style="text-transform: uppercase;">some text</span>
```

and

```
<span>SOME TEXT</span>
```

I mean both look exactly the same, but I have read somewhere that it is better to write the text normal in html and then set `text-transform: uppercase;` in CSS, but does it really make a difference? I know you can use `text-transform: uppercase;` if you want to automatically capitalize every first letter of all paragraphs on a page with pseudo-elements (`:first-letter`). I think it would even use more memory and processing/rendering time if you use `text-transform: uppercase;`.

Comment: I can't think of any good reasons to have the original text be all caps. Unless it is an acronym like NASA or FBI.

Comment: text-transform:uppercase + font-variant was a way to freeze IE6 ... for a all elements on a page with the selector *

Comment: @GCyrillus IE6 is hardly worth consideration any more, if at all.

Comment: @WesleyMurch it just tells about ressource used :) wich was too much to handle. you should look for a tool to test performance :), i have none to link to you unfortunately

Comment: @GCyrillus Performance shouldn't be a consideration either, at best it's a curiosity.

Comment: @WesleyMurch okay, i misunderstood the question :)

Comment: You ask a primarily opinion-based question and ask people not to post “opinion related answers”. There are technical differences that could be explained, but the question incorrectly claims “they function the same”, so it seems that you are not interested in the the true technical matter either.

Comment: Just want to mention here for people running in that you should be aware of using uppercase as a style if say for example you support localization on your website -- if your strings are supposed to be uppercase, better to make the actual string all caps so your translators can handle that correctly.

Comment: (A) The CSS is useful when programmatically generating HTML where input may be lowercase or mixed-case but for presentation you want [all-caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps). Ex: titles & headings in a report. (B) Also, you may be conflating this issue with *small caps* where a piece of text appears to be all uppercase but the size of the font is smaller, as is traditional in [typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography). In fine typography, alternate glyphs may be used rather than merely shrinking the regular uppercase glyphs. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a design and content perspective, the CSS option is better.

For starters, you should always use CSS for appearance. HTML is only to describe and structure content.

Now imagine you have a special term on your site that you want in all caps, but tomorrow you decide it should be in small caps or initial caps. Which is easier to change: one line in a style sheet or x number of instances buried in text?

Using CSS today will make your life easier tomorrow.

Comment: Another consideration is SERPs, having your content show as all caps when your site appears in a Google search makes it look unprofessional.

Comment: ...and also due to letter width, will show less content.

Comment: This an opinion-based answer to a question that is indeed an opinion-based question but asks people not to post “opinion related answers”. This answer additionally fails to address the question “What is the difference – –”; it just expresses personal preference to one alternative without saying what the difference is. Moreover, the opinion postulates that the use of all caps is for presentation only; this may or may not be true.